# VSTS team email alerts are not sending to members in the Azure active directory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

EDIT: Not currently supported by VSTS, [please vote for this feature here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/15985750-add-support-for-sending-team-alerts-to-individuals)

In VSTS, we have a single team with an AD group as a member of that team. The AD group is composed of many members. Our VSTS is linked to an Azure Active Directory that is synced to our internal Active Directory.

If I set up a personal alert to email me when a work item is assigned, I receive an email alert. However, if I set the same alert up as a team alert, I do not get any email alert when a work item is assigned to me. I've tried various combinations on the rules as per the attached image, but I never receive an alert.
[Alert setup for catching any work item assigned to any team member](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SctWO.jpg)

Is there something specific I need in the rule that is missing?
Is it the AD setup? Do team alerts use a different field to pull the e-mail address from than the individual alerts?
Is there anywhere else the process can fall down?

Comment: Are other alerts aren't working? (e.g. work item is created or delete) Are others could receive alert email?

Comment: @starain current work around is to use mentions (@<name>) to draw someones attention to something, so they do get emails from the system, just not the team alerts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least until recently VSTS didn't support sending notifications if the members of the team are assigned through an AD group.

I asked this some time ago [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/mitrik/status/687337837465743360) and got this response:

> Unfortunately, the notifications platform doesn't yet support sending alerts to AAD groups.

You could open an [issue on UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) to prioritize this.

Comment: Done https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/15985750-add-support-for-sending-team-alerts-to-individuals

Comment: too bad we need this